# spark csv reader : cannot read numbers with trailing dot and zero into integer

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark

So I have a csv file with numbers which are integers but have trailing .0

```
Category,ItemID
Category A,1.0
Category B,2.0
Category C,3.0
Category A,4.0
Category B,5.0
```

When I user spark csv reader, giving a schema specifying the column to be integer, it returns null.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

schema = StructType([
    StructField('Category', StringType(), False),
    StructField('ItemID', IntegerType(), False),
])

df2 = spark.read.csv(
            './output.csv',
            enforceSchema=True,
            schema=schema)
df2.show()
```

returns

```
+----------+------+
|  Category|ItemID|
+----------+------+
|  Category|  null|
|Category A|  null|
|Category B|  null|
|Category C|  null|
|Category A|  null|
|Category B|  null|
+----------+------+
```

When I read it as float, then cast the column as integer, it works.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

schema = StructType([
    StructField('Category', StringType(), False),
    StructField('ItemID', DoubleType(), False),
])

df2 = spark.read.csv(
            './output.csv',
            enforceSchema=True,
            schema=schema)

df2=df2.withColumn("ItemID",col("ItemID").cast(IntegerType()))
df2.show()
print(df2.dtypes)
```

displays

```
+----------+------+
|  Category|ItemID|
+----------+------+
|  Category|  null|
|Category A|     1|
|Category B|     2|
|Category C|     3|
|Category A|     4|
|Category B|     5|
+----------+------+
```

Is it a normal behavior ? Could I save the complex step to first read float, then cast them ?

thanks!

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70568518/1386551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is as expected.  You need to read it as float and then apply type casting.